# MySQL unknown column 'password_last_changed'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1054

When creating a user using this command:

```
create user 'foo'@localhost';
```

this error is shown:

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password_last_changed' in 'mysql.user'

Using MySQL server version: 5.7.6

I tried to add it but I don't know its data-type
How can I fix this?

Comment: Seems very .. odd if/since it is triggered by `CREATE USER`. Maybe try over on the DBA stack. (Could the default database schema itself failed a migration/update?)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html

Answer (score 68):

Apparently you upgraded your **MySQL** to 5.7 from an earlier version.

Column '*password_last_changed*' used to exist in MySQL <5.7, but was removed since 5.7

If this is the case, you have to run '**mysql_upgrade**' script to migrate some tables from the old version to the new one.

run

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

and enter your root password.

then you should have your problem solved

Comment: Loved your answer, but I wasnt needed to restart the server, I guess I have not encounter any problem yet..

Comment: For Windows systems, follow http://serverfault.com/a/538573/127106 to locate `mysql_upgrade.exe`.

Comment: I removed the restart server step, found out it's not really necessary

Comment: Nice. I would only add you to restart your MySql server, so you are sure the changes are included, with ```sudo service mysql restart```.
Take a look at [Ask Ubuntu Discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82374/how-do-i-start-stop-mysql-server)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo error in this statement - "**Column 'password_last_changed' used to exist in MySQL <5.7, but was removed since 5.7**"

When I checked, I noticed that the **password_last_changed column is present in 5.7 and not in 5.6**. In 5.6 the following error is thrown when we try to include this column in select query -

**In 5.6** -
Query: SELECT `host`, `user`, `password_last_changed` FROM mysql.user;

Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'password_last_changed' in 'field list'

[ref-image][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwXcm.png