# Error after moving MySQL DB to another computer (both Ubuntu, 14.04 and 16.04)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, exception, backup, restore

I'm trying to move a MySQL DB from version 14.14 Distrib 5.5.50 to another machine with 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13 (both machines are Ubuntu, 14.04 and 16.04 respectively)-

I've always managed to do it with these commands:

**1) Backing up on origin-computer:**

Users:

```
$ MYSQL_CONN="-uroot -ppassword"
$ mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > ${TEMP_DIR}"/"${MYSQL_DIR_NAME}"/users.sql"
```

Databases:

```
$ mysqldump -uroot -ppassword --all-databases > ${TEMP_DIR}"/"${MYSQL_DIR_NAME}"/databases_TMP.sql"
```

**2) Restoring on destiny-computer:**

Users:

```
$ mysql -uroot -ppassword < users.sql
```

Databases:

```
$ mysql -uroot -ppassword < databases_TMP.sql
```

And it has always worked for me until now.

This time, no matter the order in which I take these steps or any combination/modification on the parameters, it is not working and I can't figure out why it's not working.

Every time I finish the process, when I launch the MySQL Workbench and click any user, inmmediately I get this error message:

**"Unhandled exception: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"**

I have no clue what can I do to solve it, so any idea will be really welcomed.

Comment: Could you run in command line "mysql  -uroot -ppassword" and than "select * from mysql.user;" to check if user were imported properly ?

Comment: Good idea. No, users weren't imported properly. Now I know much better what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else had the same problem:

Using the **mysqldump** command instead of the one I posted in my question worked fine:

```
$ mysqldump -uroot -ppass --all-databases > databases.sql
```

However, because of MySQL versions on both computers I also had to go through this other problem:

[MySQL unknown column 'password_last_changed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455181/mysql-unknown-column-password-last-changed)

And finally now I have everything working again.